# PHP Remove the last part of the string, determined by first character occurrence, starting from the end of the string

Tags: php, substr

The strings always end with a hyphen followed by a variable size integer.
For instance:

foo-bar-baz-132
another-55-string-961370

How can I remove the last hyphen (first occurrence from right to left) plus any character to the right?

Comment: substr and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php could be used, regex, explode, preg_split, probably 5 other functions. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You also have 20 questions without an accepted answer. Is that correct or have you forgotten to accept some/unsure how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$string = 'foo-bar-baz-132 another-55-string-961370';
$result = substr ($string , 0, strrpos($string, '-'));
echo $result;
```

Source

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php